# Modifying CKEditor to allow for an exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have the following dynamically CKEditor function being called:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  var lang = new Array;
  lang[1] = 'en';
  $('textarea').each(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('class') == 'editorHook' || ($(this).attr('name') != 'message' && $(this).attr('class') != 'noEditor'))
    {
      index = $(this).attr('name').match(/\d+/);
      if (index == null) index = 1;
      CKEDITOR.replace($(this).attr('name'),
      {
         coreStyles_underline : { element : 'u' },
         width : 760,
         language: lang[index]
      });
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

What I would like to do is add in a bit of customization to one specific HTML Text Editor field:

```
$(function() {
    $('#your_textarea').ckeditor({
        toolbar: 'Full',
        enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
        shiftEnterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_P
    });
});
```

I tried to edit the first set of coding to allow the customization, but the CKEDitor isn't affected. I even tried to make this change that worked for all TEXTAREA's which is what I didn't want to do.:

```
if ($(this).attr('class') == 'editorHook' || ($(this).attr('name') != 'message' && $(this).attr('class') != 'noEditor'))
{
  index = $(this).attr('name').match(/\d+/);
  if (index == null) index = 1;
  CKEDITOR.replace($(this).attr('name'),
    {
      coreStyles_underline : { element : 'u' },
      width : 760,
      language: lang[index],
      enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
      shiftEnterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_P

    });
}
```

How or where to edit this JavaScript to allow me to define the options for one very specific field?

Comment: Why don't you pass configurations conditionally to `CKEDITOR.replace($(this).attr('name'), ... );`?

Comment: How do I pass them in? Can you submit a code example?

Comment: After a bit of fussing, I managed to figure this out. Turns out I had to do the conditional BEFORE the one I listed above.